# Will Windows 7 update if the computer is turned off at the time it is set to auto-update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, automatic-update

While using win7, I find a windows update function, and an action center will show at the right bottom corner of the computer notification area.

I set it to auto install the important updates at 5pm everyday, while at that time, my computer is always off. So does that mean the update will never be installed?

How to make it happen?

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly you are asking. Are you trying to ask the following? "I have my computer set to automatically install "Important Updates" everyday at 5pm, but the computer is never turned on at 5PM. How can I make it install updates regardless of my computer being turned on." If that is your questions, that is impossible for your computer to install updates when it is turned off unless you have BIOS set to boot the computer prior to 5PM so it can be ready to install updates at 5PM. I would put this as an answer, but I am only assuming the questions, which is very obscure...

Answer (score 1):

`So does that mean the update will never be installed?`

Yes, it can't auto-update while the computer is turned off.

`How to make it happen?`

Just set it to auto-update at an hour in which your computer is always on. If you are doing this because you don't want to update while you are using your computer, then set it to the time when you usually eat dinner or something, and leave the computer on while you do it.

An alternative, as mentioned by David on the comments, is to set your computer to auto-turn on in the BIOS. Note that not all BIOS support that. To do so:

1. Enter your BIOS by pressing <kbd>del</kbd> or whatever other key is indicated on boot-up - when the computer is turning on.
2. Look for `Resume on RTC Alarm` or `Power on By RTC Alarm` or `Resume by Alarm` and enable it.
3. Set the time to 4:55PM or something close to when you want it to update. Save and quit.

That's it, your computer will automatically turn on 5min before the auto-update and then Windows will update. You can also make a `.bat` so it will automatically turn off after a few hours or even after the update is finished (by looking for the process using `tasklist | find`).

Comment: Thanks both, you got my meaning, and it seems the right solution.

Comment: @Alex: An additional question you can address - if WU was skipped because the PC was off, does Windows attempt it whenever it is finally run?